# Convert shared dataset to embedded SSRS

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, dataset, ssrs-2008

I unthinkingly converted my embedded dataset to a shared dataset in SSRS.  Is it possible to reverse that?  I have changes I need to make to some calculated fields.  What options do I have? SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1):

Embarrassing...all I needed to do was double click on the shared dataset under "Shared Datasets" in solution explorer.  You can edit the fields from there. :\

Answer (score 0):

Rollback changes in your version control system.